# InnerText to replace <br> with space

Tags: c#, html-agility-pack

Ive been trying to find a built in solution/setting in the `HtmlAgilityPack`.

Im facing some issues when there is a `<br>` inside a parent node. Other nodes also but I used `<br>` for this question. See below example.

```
HtmlDocument doc = new HtmlDocument();
doc.LoadHtml("<p>This is a<br>test</p>");

var text = doc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//p");

foreach (var i in text)
{
  Console.WriteLine(i.InnerText);
}
```

This produces the following result

```
This is atest
```

Im looking for a solution that gives this result

```
This is a test
```

Is there a setting I can use to have the `<br>` nodes replace with a space in the `InnerText` property, or am I forced to execute a `Replace("<br>"," ")` on the text before loading it into a `HtmlDocument`?

Comment: Make a `List<string>` (`textNodes`). In the foreach loop: `textNodes.Add(string.Join(" ", i.ChildNodes.Where(n => n.NodeType == HtmlNodeType.Text).Select(n => n.InnerText)));` Disclaimer: written here, not tested.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried this, i think giving space before/after 
 should give you desired result.

```
<p>This is a <br> test</p>
```

Comment: thanks but this I know. Im asking if there is a setting in the HtmlAgilitypack I could utillize.

Comment: Thats not an anwser to this problem. Because he might not control how the html looks like. So doing that is making a new problem: "How do we make sure theres always a space between <br>"?

Answer (score 1):

I believe you could do something like this.

```
foreach (HtmlNode node in doc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//br"))
    node.ParentNode.ReplaceChild(doc.CreateTextNode(" "), node);
```

It selects the `<br>` nodes and replaces them with text nodes containing a space character. You could even use a newline character if you want to preserve the line break.

Comment: Thanks James. unfortunatley the definition for SafeSelectNodes doesnt exists for me. Which version are you using?

Comment: Try replacing it with just `SelectNodes`.